# jQuery Stacked Draggables: Is it possible to keep one div on top of every stacked draggable divs?

Tags: jquery, stack, draggable

So this is the code I'm using and I need #div2, #div3 and #div4 to stay under #div1.

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#div2, #div3, #div4" ).draggable({ stack: "#div2, #div3, #div4" });
  });
```

I have tried z-index but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `stop` event to loop over the elements and adjust z-indexes

```
$( "#div2, #div3, #div4" ).draggable({

    stop: function() {
       /* adjust z-indexes here*/
    }

})
```